# error (xcode): target debug_unpack_ios failed: exception: failed to codesign in Flutter and IOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, xcode

To fully understand and address the issue, it's important to read the entire text. If you've recently updated your macOS to version 14, Xcode 15 and are encountering the following error when using Flutter:

```
(Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code)
```

[image]

Here's a breakdown of the problem:

1. **Running on Android Emulator:** When attempting to run your application in Android Studio on an Android emulator, it functions without any issues.
2. **Running on Simulator (iOS):** However, when you try to run the app on the iOS simulator, it fails to work.
3. **Running on Xcode:** Surprisingly, if you open the application in Xcode and run it there, it functions correctly on the simulator. Yet, in Android Studio, the issue persists.

Many online solutions suggest accessing "Keychain Access > Login Certificates" and deleting all Apple certificates. You may have already tried these solutions on platforms like Stack Overflow and Apple communities, but they yielded no results.

Answer (score 11):

I had similar weird **codesign** errors when compiling flutter in VSC on mac. This only started to occur when I upgraded to macOS Sonoma 1.40

So, this is how I fixed it:

**First Issue:** My flutter project was no longer compiling and running via VSC but it was when building within Xcode. Was getting `code sign` errors and compilation was failing. My project files was stored within iCloud Drive and sync was on.
**Solution:** So I move entire project across to a local folder on my HD and that seems to fix that issue.

**Second Issue:** Then another runtime issue/error popped up around `firebaseinitialization` being called before firebase was initialised during runtime.
**Solution:** I found that Xcode was not picking up `GoogleService-Info.plist` file in Xcode running directory so I had to add it manually in Xcode and that fixed that issue

Answer (score 1):

If your project folder is sync in icloud drive simply by turning it off resolve the problem, that how i resolved my issue, or try signing out your i-cloud id. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Move your project to a non-cloud sync folder - this is a known issue:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/133191

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I recently bought an M2. I saw that this error occurs because I am trying to run the file that is on icloud.
[image]
[image]

The way I found was to disable synchronization

[image]

But you can also solve it by creating a local folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I attempted, which appears to be the key to the solution:

- **Remove All Related Components:** Delete your Flutter SDK, iOS developer tools, including Xcode, simulator, and Dart SDK. Essentially, remove everything associated with Flutter.
- **Reinstallation:** Reinstall Flutter and all its dependencies from scratch.
- **Flutter Doctor:** Execute `flutter doctor` to confirm that Flutter is correctly installed, and there are no issues with your setup.

This approach, in my opinion, was the decisive factor in resolving the problem:

- **Logout and Re-login:** Log out of all your accounts on your Mac, including iCloud and Xcode. Ensure that your Mac is entirely disassociated from your iCloud account, and then log in once again.

Following this step-by-step approach should help you overcome the issue you encountered after updating to macOS 15 and encountering the Xcode CodeSign error. It's important to note that software development environments can be sensitive to system updates, and a clean reinstallation often serves as the solution to such issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a CI context, you should unlock the mac keychain. You can do so with the following command :

`security unlock-keychain -p <password> login.keychain`