# Flutter IOS Issues

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, mobile

I've started attempting app development with flutter on a mac, using VS Code. Flutter is fully downloaded, when I run flutter doctor that all appears to be fine and I'm able to run the code on an android simulator with no issues. However, when i try to run it on an IOS sim I'm just getting this error. This is from a brand new flutter project with no changes made at all.[image: error]

I've tried changing some settings I thought would help within xcode but I can't seem to get it working. The simulator itself will load fine but as soon as I run any code I have the issue. I've got no prior experience with flutter or xcode and I can't work out where to go from here.

If anyone can help it would be massively appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error (xcode): target debug\_unpack\_ios failed: exception: failed to codesign in Flutter and IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207505/error-xcode-target-debug-unpack-ios-failed-exception-failed-to-codesign-in)